# OnTouchListener inside fragment stops Viewpager swipe events

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener

I am having a Viewpager inside a fragment and when i am trying to implement OnTouchListener on this Viewpager, the touch gesture is working completely fine but after implementing OnTouchListener, i am not able to switch between my Viewpager items. I am not sure what i am doing wrong and even i am not getting any clue on this.

Here is my OnTouchListener code:

```
lsArticlesViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    downXValue = motionEvent.getX();
                    downYValue = motionEvent.getY();
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    float currentX = motionEvent.getX();
                    float currentY = motionEvent.getY();

                    if (downYValue < currentY) {
                        swipeUpTv.startAnimation(animBounce);
                    }
                    if (downYValue > currentY) 
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are consuming that event, so `ViewPager` is not changing. Return `false` from `onTouch` method. 
Check official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch(android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent)) of `onTouch` method.
Return

> True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise.

Comment: if i am returning "false" from onTouch menthod Viewpager is working fine, but onTouchListener stops working. And  if i am returning "true" from onTouch menthod onTouchListener is working fine, but Viewpager stops working.

Comment: onTouchListener stops working after returning `false` because `ViewPager` is consuming the touch event for sliding fragments

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now its working like a charm. Thanks for pointing out the problem :)

Comment: If you want to detect touch event of your `ViewPager` every time it is touched you have to care a subclass of  `ViewPager` and override `dispatchTouchEvent` method . Then Every time you touch  to `ViewPager` method `dispatchTouchEvent ` will be get called. Make sure you return false for not consuming it.

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped. :)